# GStreamer Android.mk to CMakeList.txt

Tags: android, cmake, gstreamer

The code attached is the Android.mk file from the Official GStreamer Website, which is built by NDKBuild. I am currently done with all the function needed for my application then only I realized the existing application (which, I will implement the function from the application that I had done developed it) is built by CMake and I am having difficulty in translating GStreamer build file from Android.mk to CMakeList.txt. I know this is not a coding service platform, but this is the last step for my project and I really need your help.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tutorial-3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tutorial-3.c dummy.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/arm
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/armv7
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/arm64
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/x86
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/x86_64
else
$(error Target arch ABI not supported: $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
endif

GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECTS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET)
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-video-1.0 gobject-2.0
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_LIBS      := -liconv
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
```

Comment: Please be more clear with what you need and I may be able to help. Also check out the Gstreamer IRC channel http://irc.lc/freenode/gstreamer where you can get a lot of help.

Comment: I have 2 different applications on my hand. A existing app and the one that I done with slightly modification of the code of from the GStreamer for Android Official Page. The thing is, the existing app JNI is built with CMake, but not for the GStreamer, as it is NDKBuild. In order to use GStreamer in the existing app I need to convert the Android.mk to parts of the content in CMakeList.txt, but I have no idea how to do so, and not even know it is workable or possible or not.

Comment: Witch platform is the CMake code for, windows, linux or something else?

Comment: Also I think the gstreamer cmake build system is no longer the standard build instead they use some type of python build. I have built gstreamer on most platforms in my work so perhaps I may be able to help. If I understand the problem correctly you have an application that is built for android and now you want to build it for another platform?

Comment: CMake in Android Studio. No. What I mean is, I have and existing Android app, but I wish to implement the streaming function of GStreamer from Raspberry Pi to Android surface view. So to prevent I make the existing app not workable anymore, I try to build the necessary function on another new app first. Well, everything works fine now and it's time for me to transfer all the function from the new app back to the existing app, but only I realized the existing app used CMake instead of ndkbuild, and I can't change anything on the existing app as it is a released version.

Comment: So I think the only solution is to convert the Android.mk to fit in the CMakeList.txt, but I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: Most of the code is based on the link : https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/android/video.html?gi-language=c

Comment: "I know this is not a coding service platform" - Yes. We can **help** you with the **specific problem** you faced when handle convertion. But we won't convert the whole file for you.

Comment: I wish to do so, but I have no idea how to start with it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Looks similar to this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056149/include-gstreamer-in-android-ndk-project-that-uses-cmake-cmakelists-txt-and-no/66932119#66932119

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to build gstreamer for another platform. You are attempting to do this using Cmake. This used to be the way to build it for Windows but has been replaced by a build based on the meason framework. You can read more here https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-build

The positive news is that it is really simple to build gstreamer using meason, compared to using Cmake.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the thing is I'm trying to built it in Android Studio, which, all the JNI had built by using CMake (Those OpenCV things...).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android Studio unfortunatly. If you want to build using cmake you need to make sure all the required libs are in place. This took me at least two weeks when I tried it. But I was not doing it in android studio so it could be even harder in there.

My best tip is probably to go onto the IRC channel and check there. The people who hang out there usually answer really quickly.